# already contains entry 'AndroidManifest.xml', cannot overwrite | Android Studio Arctic Fox

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

Olá, boa tarde.

Tudo bem?

Estou enfrentando alguns problemas após a atualização do meu Android Studio. Alguém sabe como solucionar?

app\build\outputs\apk\dev\debug\app-dev-debug.apk' already contains entry 'AndroidManifest.xml', cannot overwrite

Obrigadooo!!!!